# Unit test node.js mock file system open errors

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, istanbul

I would like to improve my code coverage on this function :

```
function openArchiveFilePath(zipFilepath, next) {

  var fullyQualifiedZipFilepath = path.resolve(zipFilepath);

  fs.open(zipFilepath, 'r', openFile);

  function openFile(err, fd) {
    if (err) {
      if (err.code === FS_ERROR_CODE.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR_CODE) {
        formatErrorMessageAndLog(err, "photo archive file (%s) doesn't exist.",
          fullyQualifiedZipFilepath);
        return next(err);
      }

      if (err.code === FS_ERROR_CODE.FILE_PERMISSIONS_ERROR_CODE) {
        formatErrorMessageAndLog(err,
          "photo archive file (%s) cannot be read, insufficient permissions.",
          fullyQualifiedZipFilepath);
        return next(err);
      }

      formatErrorMessageAndLog(err, "photo archive file (%s) cannot be open.",
          fullyQualifiedZipFilepath);
      return next(err);
    }

    return next(null, zipFilepath, fd);
  }
}
```

I am using mocha as a testing framework and istanbul for code coverage. So far I could cover the case where the file isn't found or where the permissions isn't correct (respectively trying to open a non existent file, or opening a file i created from whom I removed read permissions).

However how could i try to generate a more generic `Error` that `fs.open` could throw so that the code

```
  formatErrorMessageAndLog(err, "photo archive file (%s) cannot be open.",
      fullyQualifiedZipFilepath);
  return next(err);
```

Would be covered ?